# Candlestick shows two colors (up trend & down trend)

Tags: highcharts

This is an angular2 app (2.4.8), webpack using highcharts.

I am updating the chart with minute bars from the database.  I make timed calls to the database, then with the array returned (it maybe just 1 row, it maybe more, depending if data is keeping up).  Below, 'x' is the array returned.

```
for (let i of x) {
    let point = [new Date(i.DateTime).valueOf(), i.OpeningPrice,
          i.HighPrice, i.LowPrice, i.ClosingPrice];
    this.chart.get('sA0').addPoint(point, true);
}
```

The problem of a single bar indicating both up and down trend, as seen in my screenshot, the one bar has green on top & red below.

[image]

Comment: That looks like you have two points in the same place. I suggest to use [`point.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Series.addPoint) to update an existing point and `series.addPoint()` only when point does not exist.